# Кастомная анимция скролла | SWIPER | REACT

Tags: reactjs, swiper

Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать кастомную анимацию элементов при скролле в swiper? Например, я хочу при пролистывании слайда активный элемент делать больше на 30% и показать 2 блока.

**ВАЖНО:** я знаю, как сделать это при помощи css, но мне надо сделать именно планые изменения при скролл. (Скролл делается через drag)

Comment: Хз, но можете все таки юзать css, просто через javascript много раз в секунду менять эти стили с изменениями, и получится плавность. Хотя это 100% костыль, возможно Вы не найдете правильного решения для таких специфических задач

Comment: @artemgh, я решил задачу с помощью CardSlider, хоть и пришлось переписывать немного этот компонент, чтобы он под мои задачи подходил.

Comment: Ответьте на свой вопрос)

Comment: @artemgh я не вижу вопроса в комментарии

Comment: В смысле ответьте на свой же личный вопрос, о том как Вы решили это с помощью CardSlider